# De Rham cohomology group of the Klein Bottle

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms

I need to compute all the cohomology rings of the Klein Bottle.

I want to apply the Mayer-Vietoris sequence. Here I'm using the same good open cover suggested by the Wikipedia page :-)
[image]

It's reasonable to think that the blue set is a Moebius band and each connected component of the intersection as well. What it's not clear to me is why the red set is also a Moebius band.

Any help?

Comment: I had the impression that the Kleinbottle is not a vector bundle.

Comment: I thought it was a fiber bundle

Comment: still it is a fiber bundle! . .  to be a vector bundle you need that the fiber is a vectorspace

Comment: yes, I'm sorry.  Otherwise the fiber should be an euclidean space, right?

Comment: Can I use that homotopy argument above in any case?

Comment: consider the torus: He is also a $S^1$-bundle over the $S^1$ itself, but he has another homotopy type than $S^1$

Comment: yes, that's true! Thanks

Comment: I've just edited the post. Actually, just deleted the vector bundle part

Comment: that good 'cuz other wise, it could be a magnet to the f-downvoters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cut open the square vertically in the middle and connect the two vertical lines, you would get the same picture, only the red part now is connected and the blue part is separated.

Comment: That's even less clear to me. In fact, while on the blue set the equivalence relation is acting just on two horizontal edges (like a Moebius strip, indeed) , on the red set the equivalence relation is acting both on the horizontal and on the vertical edges and so I would think its not a Moebius band.

Comment: It's kinda hard to explain this without interaction. I would recommend you to review the canonical representation of compact surfaces. "Equivalence relation" is a very formal way to form these spaces. It is helpful to think of the two vertical lines as just one line on the surface (really, how would you think of the "equivalence relation" in the case of Mobius band -- It just a path on the band. Another example is when we look at the world map, the left most and right most longitudes are just the same one). Also, Klein bottle is a vector bundle over $S^1$? Did you mean Mobius' band?

Comment: That's quite difficult for me, because what you're saying requires a detailed imagination, but I've understood a bit.  No, I meant the Klein bottle, but I was not sure :)

Comment: I would suggest you actually to pull a piece of paper, color and mark it like the picture. Draw the middle vertical line, mark it with upward arrows. Then glue the two vertical edges (This is quotient out the "equivalence relation"). Now cut it open and see the result.

Comment: Okay! AndI have just realized that the intersection of the two open sets are not two Moebius bands, but two cylinders

Comment: Two? How about one? -- The blue lines connect and same for the red lines. To see that, use the said piece of paper, but only glue the horizontal edges (in the opposite direction) without any cutting.

Comment: Got it thanks!!!